# Register HTTP_Interceptor in @component and pass there dynamic data

Tags: angular, interceptor, angular-http-interceptors

I have big project and i need create HTTP_Interceptor for adding there some headers which can be added from component where interceptor are registered in providers array.

My component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-test',
    templateUrl: './test.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss'],
    providers: [
      {
          provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
          useClass: TestInterceptorService,
          useValue: 'test data' <- i need pass that data to interceptor and add it in request's header
      }
   ]
})
```

My interceptor:

```
@Injectable()
export class TestInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor() {}

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        console.log("HTTP_INTERCEPTORS"); <- this is not showing
        return next.handle(req);
    }

}
```

And I didn't register it in the module

Passing data can be various from components. Is it real pass data like this?
There is other way by adding header in each api, but our project is huge.

If it is real, any comment or answer can help me to solve that task)

Comment: You can do that by using a service to hold that data? That service can be simply DI’t in the constructor of the interceptor.

Comment: @MikeOne, i thought about it, but i don't like that idea. But also if i won't find any decision, i will do this)

Comment: Quite a standard approach? But sure, I don’t know what exactly your scenario is. If the data you need is - for example - based on build time variables, it might be better to use something like an injection token.